# Reconnect to a bonded Peripheral after toggling iOS Bluetooth off/on

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, btle

I am not new to iOS, but am relatively new to CoreBluetooth and BTLE in general. Using devices running iOS 10 or later ( currently 11.2 ), I have found that if bluetooth is toggled off and on, the bonded peripheral can no longer be accessed.

After doing a bit of debugging, it seems that once bonded, the security information saved on both ends includes the address of each peer. The iOS side remembers the peripheral just fine, but after turning Bluetooth off and on again, the address of the iOS device changes itself, so to the peripheral its currently registered bonded peer (address) no longer exists. For this reason, connection between the two is no longer possible until the bonding information on the peripheral side is cleared ( Peripheral device performs direct advertisement once bonded so that only its bonded peer can see it ).

I would like to know
A) is there anyway to retain the same address on the iOS side after toggling Bluetooth off/on
B) If the address cannot be retained/recalled, what is the usual method for dealing with this sort of situation?

I have searched through the Core Bluetooth Programming reference and have googled this problem to the best of my ability, but to no avail.

---

**Peripheral output via serial connection while bonded with the iOS centra**l:

> BTA=001EC0461948  Name=The_Lock1948  Connected=**7DD350CC912D**,1 
>   Bonded=7DD350CC912D,1  Server Service=00000001  Features=20000000
>   TxPower=4

**iOS Bluetooth off/on, then reconnect with the exact same iOS device**:

> BTA=001EC0461948  Name=The_Lock1948  Connected=**5DDC08C0B0A3**,1 
>   Bonded=7DD350CC912D,1 Server  Service=00000001  Features=24000000 
>   TxPower=4

As you can see, the "Connected" address has changed while the peripheral remains bonded to the previous address. The only difference between the two is a toggle of the BT setting. When I say BT power off/on, I mean really turn the power off and on, not the "Allow New Connections" setting in iOS 11+.

By the way, just to add to this, I have seen 2 other BTLE peripheral devices ( keyboards ) that cannot reconnect after a iOS BT power toggle until they are reset in some fashion.

Comment: Two things: 
1. Please refer to your ios device as a "central" and the device you are trying to connect as "peripheral". 
2. "The iOS side remembers the peripheral just fine, but after turning Bluetooth off and on again, the address of the iOS device changes itself". Can you quote this? I've never seen that issue with iOS device whenever I've worked on them.

Comment: @AnjilDhamala I have updated the original post with serial output showing demonstrating the problem.

Comment: if reconnection requires you to reset your peripheral, how come you are able to connect and provide info on what's bonded and what's connected?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala In order to get the bonded/connected information after toggling iOS bluetooth setting, I set the peripheral to a less secure, "none direct" advertisement setting. In that mode, peripheral advertisements can be picked up by any scanning central, even when the peripheral is bonded. It was to obtain the bonded/connected information only.

Comment: Unless your peripheral cannot bond to more than one central, you shouldn't encounter this problem. iPhones can bond to several devices and and be connected to only one at a time. Bonding is sort of like 'logging in'. You can log in once and then ask the browser to remember your credentials and you won't be bothered the next time. There could be 5 different facebook accounts, for example, remembered by a browser but a user can only log into one at a time. Here is another Q&A that might be useful. https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/64035/unable-to-receive-directed-advertisements/

Comment: @AnjilDhamala The peripheral device can only bond to one central at a time. In the end, we decided to add an additional layer of functionality to side step this problem, though I would hardly call it a proper solution. Thank you though.

Comment: I'd like to know what that 'additional layer of functionality' is.